# Including Javascript options

Tags: theme-development, jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

For a Wordpress Theme I know javascript files (ending in .js) must be included using `wp_enqueue_script` in `functions.php` but how do I include additional javascript code? For example, say I need to add this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    jQuery.supersized({
        slides:
        [
             'http://google.com',
             'http://google.co.uk'
        ]
    });
});
```

Where would I put this? Do I put it within `<script>` tags in the header.php?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to pass data from php to your javascript:

```
wp_register_script(
    'wpa_script',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js',
    array('jquery'),
    null,
    false
);

wp_localize_script(
    'wpa_script',
    'WPAData',
    array(
        'slides' => array( 'http://google.com', 'http://google.co.uk' )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put it inside a callback, hooked into the correct action:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpse88383_print_scripts' );

function wpse88383_print_scripts() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(function($){
                    jQuery.supersized({
                        slides:
                        [
                        'http://google.com',
                        'http://google.co.uk'
                        ]
                    });
                });
            </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since WP 4.5 the correct way to do this is to use [`wp_add_inline_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/). This function preprends or appends your script to an enqueued script. For instance, you could append your script to `jquery` like this:

```
$script = 'jQuery(function($){
  jQuery.supersized({
    slides:
    [
         "http://google.com",
         "http://google.co.uk"
    ]
  });
  });';
wp_add_inline_script ('jquery', $script);
```